# Why US-ASCII encoding file contains non-US-ASCII characters?

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding, ascii

When I execute `file -i file_name` in Linux shell, the result is:

```
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

But this file contains a non US-ASCII character `â`, which is Extended ASCII.

If I modify the file and save it as a new file by Vim, the new file's format changes to ISO-8859-1.

I tried to generate a new file by Java using the code below, the new file's format is ISO-8859-1 too.

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(in);
     BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(out);
     BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

    while (bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

If I use `iconv` to change the new file's format from ISO-8859-1 to US-ASCII, it says:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 15
```

I don't know why this US-ASCII encoding file can contain a non US-ASCII character. And how do I create a file like this?

Thanks!

Comment: `file` doesn't examine the whole file, it's just heuristic.

Comment: That's the reason: `file` will only look at the beginning of the file and will give you its best guess. That guess is definitely far from being guaranteed correct (though, to be fair, it usually guesses pretty well). Also note that the Java code you post will do absolutely no encoding conversion and will also most likely corrupt the file (at the very least attach garbage \0 bytes at the end), since you have to take the return value of `read` to know how many bytes to `write`.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  Find a way to include `â` in an ASCII file?  Do you want it to appear as `a` in the file?

Comment: @choroba @JoachimSauer Thanks a lot, `file` command should be the problem. The original file contains ten thousand lines. If I extract one line which contains the non-US-ASCII character from the original file and save it as a new file, then the new file is ISO-8859-1 because that `file` only checks this line and gets the correct format.